# Is my analysis of this paragraph correct based on the punctuation used?

Tags: grammaticality, meaning-in-context, punctuation, meaning, first-conditional

> Your services may be terminated by giving 01 (one) weeks’ notice or payment of pro-rata salary in lieu thereof during probation, and by 01 (one) months’ notice or payment of one month’s salary in lieu thereof after confirmation, by either party, except in instances of dismissal, discharge or termination for misconduct.

According to my interpretation -
a) If the reason for termination refers - 'if any instances of dismissal causes discharge, In such condition notice period is not applicable or given.

b) If the reason for termination refers - Termination for misconduct occurs, In such condition notice period is not applicable or given.

Is my analysis of this paragraph correct based on the punctuation used? If not, please explain.

Comment: I think this needs a little clarity on the a) and b) sections. Are you trying to interpret the whole paragraph or just the last section regarding dismissal for misconduct?

Comment: No, this is not what it means. It might mean *dismissal for misconduct, discharge for misconduct, or termination for misconduct.* This might imply that there are different legal meanings of *dismissal, discharge,* and *termination* wherever you are — I have no idea whether this is true, or what the different legal meanings could be.

Comment: The possessive of *week* and *month* (specifically pointed out to be singular), is incorrect. And that's just the first issue I see with the passage. It's not well written, so I wouldn't put much faith in any interpretation of it.